# Prevent button permanently disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

In  below code when I click 'Vote' a vote results screen is displayed but when I click 'Return to poll' the poll is redisplayed but the button 'Show Options' is no longer visible. Is there a way to prevent this button from being hidden when a 'Return to poll' is clicked.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/E2gku/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/5968383/">This is a test question ?</a></noscript>

<style>
.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 200px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="showanswer" value="Show Options"/>');

        $('.pds-vote').css('display' , 'none');
        $('.pds-answer').css('display' , 'none');
        $('.pds-vote-button').css('display' , 'none');
        $('.pds-view-results').css('display' , 'none'); 

    $('.showanswer').on('click', function () {

            $('.pds-vote').show();
             $('.pds-answer').show();
             $('.pds-vote-button').show();
             $('.pds-view-results').show();

        $('.showanswer').hide();
        $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="hideanswer" value="Hide Options"/>');

        $('.hideanswer').on('click', function () {
                $('.pds-vote').hide();
                 $('.pds-answer').hide();
                 $('.pds-vote-button').hide();
                 $('.pds-view-results').hide();
                $('.showanswer').show();
                 $('.hideanswer').hide();
        });

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: That code looks WET, dripping... I'm sure you can reduce ALL that to around 5 lines if you use a shared class and cache your selectors.

Comment: `.css('display' , 'none') === .hide()`, and even without shared class you can concatenate all those selectors into a single one: `$('.pds-vote, .pds-answer, .pds-vote-button, .pds-view-results')`

Comment: Not sure if it's the best idea to hack around with external script but have you seen that PollDaddy has an open API? http://support.polldaddy.com/api/ If it suits your needs then it may be more reliable...

Comment: @Dmitry Pashkevich I agree, not the best idea, but I have no choice in this case

Comment: @Fabrício Matté selecting on the .css instead of using .hide() is much faster, which is why im not using .hide

Comment: `.hide()` is more readable and performs over 28k operations/sec even in an old computer. But ok, `.css('display', 'none')` is slightly faster. Now, if you're **really** concerned about performance in the miliseconds, you wouldn't be creating a new jQuery object for each class and calling `.css('display', 'none')` for each of them - which is not only much slower, but also much harder to maintain and a prime exemple of [WET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#Violating_DRY) code as commented by @elclanrs.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté I noticed a visible speed improvment when hiding the poll in iE8, when acccessing the css directly instead of using .hide() but maybe it was a caching improvment, im not sure. yes i agree the code needs to tidied up

Comment: I see. Yeah, older versions of IE tend to have a ***very*** slow JS engine, it might make a difference when hiding multiple elements at once..

Comment: I'd say don't obsess with mini-micro-tiny-optimizations and concentrate on stuff that would really make a difference in performance, like caching selectors, appending everything at last...all the common issues of performance start there

Comment: I've submitted a fix, didn't test it on older versions of IE. Hope you don't mind the drying I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event delegation to re-append the button when the user clicks to go back to the question:

```
$('body').on('click', '.pds-return-poll', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="showhideanswer" value="Hide Options"/>');
    }, 10);
});
```

I've also dried up your code, just a little:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pds-answer, .pds-vote').css('display' , 'none');
    $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="showhideanswer" value="Show Options"/>');

    $('body').on('click', '.pds-return-poll', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.pds-question').append('<input type="button" class="showhideanswer" value="Hide Options"/>');
        }, 10);
    }).on('click', '.showhideanswer', function() {
        $('.pds-answer, .pds-vote').toggle();
        if (this.value == 'Show Options')
            $(this).val('Hide Options');
        else
            $(this).val('Show Options');
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/E2gku/8/).

The timeout is because your default function takes precedence, so interpret this timeout as a deferred object.

And obviously, as the button is being added dynamically, it will also require event delegation as in my code above (either that or re-binding the event handlers, your choice).

​**edit:** Fixed a bug in Firefox.

**edit2:** Dried it up a little more. Selectors are only being used once now so I discarded the selector caching, as the `$(document).ready`'s selector can't be re-used inside the `showhideanswer`'s `click` handler because, for some reason, your plugin's developer decided to create new elements when you go to the results page and back to the vote page instead of re-using the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

Polldaddy doesn't hide your button, instead it will replace the `.innerHTML` of `#PDI_container5968383` and thus remove your new button entirely. Have a look at the function `PDV_go5968383()` in the PD script:

```
function PDV_go5968383(){
    /* other code */
    // PDV_html5968383 is prepared HTML for the container
    _$("PDI_container5968383").innerHTML = PDV_html5968383;
    /* other code */
}
```

This will remove all your additions. You could add the buttons outside of the PD container and position them with CSS. This would prevent them from being removed.